# How can I validate website color scheme?

Tags: usability-testing, usability-study, human-interface-guideline, color-perception

A friend of mine asked me to validate the color scheme of his revamped website. The color was chosen by (non-technical) top management and it doesn't follow a modern color scheme.

Is there any way to get insights into user perception objectively? How to approach that in the user testing sessions?

Comment: There is a similar question here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/106049/how-to-argue-for-color-choices

Answer (score 4):

### Simply ask a handful of users what they think.

Try to focus on the same demographic as the people that your app is targeted towards.

Ask them about contrast, mood, readability and style.

For testing accessibility use the [color contrast checker.](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) It will give you a good arguing point against the boss's color choice if it fails the accessibility tests.

Comment: I like this answer because it's short. I answered a similar question before and feel a lot of it also applies: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/115549/22257

Answer (score 1):

First you should consider the product or industry for that website is.Then you can have a basic idea which color will be good. and further you can go the complete color combinations by using color wheel and test contrast further using [Contrast Checker](https://contrastchecker.com/)